# How to call List Item in SharePoint Using REST API in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal

I'm want to consume share point rest API service to call from Android previously i use to call share point web service through the graph API but while generating token from graph API its not support in below URL, does any one have any solution about this problem.

https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Announcements')/Items

```
 JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, MSGRAPH_URL,
            parameters,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            /* Successfully called graph, process data and send to UI */
            Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());


            updateGraphUI(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.getAccessToken());
            return headers;
        }
    };

    Log.d(TAG, "Adding HTTP GET to Queue, Request: " + request.toString());

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            3000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(request);
```

I already tried with MSAL library but its does not work with this token.
**Update**: i used to call graph api for janrating token but i got 401 error with this above mention URL.

Comment: hey guys, any help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a SharePoint API, so you will need a SharePoint token instead of a Graph token. These are two separate APIs with different authentications.

To get a SharePoint token you will need to register an App in SharePoint itself or use the users username + password if available in your app.

Also see:
https://spshell.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html
https://shareyourpoint.net/2017/01/25/operations-using-rest-in-sharepoint-online-authorization/

For Graph, use an URL like this to get your list items:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select=Column1,Column2)

You will probably need to do several calls to get your site ID and list ID first.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: yes i want to call share point API only but i did not find any API reference or any example to how to pass these  header in android like post man, do you have any reference or example

Comment: I'm not an android expert but from what I see you are already passing the header in your code. Does that not work when you use the correct SPO token? I can't see what authResult does to get the token, so I'm going to have to assume this will return the token needed. For debugging, try pasting in a token you know works (like in postman).

Comment: ok, what i did, store home page cookies like rffa and fed auth in local storage and pass as header to call rest API, is that a correct way to call share point rest API or any other solution you have.